# Pasar valor de parametro a consulta antes de ejecutarse en power bi

Tags: sql, tsql, powerbi

Estoy buscando ejecutar una consulta para extraccion de datos desde sql pero me gustaria saber si power bi tiene la funcionalidad de pasar el valor de un parametro en por ejemplo:fechainicial y fechafinal al query y que este valor sea capturado por el usuario antes de ser ejecutada la consulta, es decir similar a lo que tiene Reporting Services, donde es muy sencillo generar los parametros de fecha y automaticamente los pasa al query.

```
select CARLINE,veh_numserie AS SERIE,veh_anmodelo as MODELO,VENDEDOR,VENTA,VTE_FECHDOCTO AS FECHAFACTURA ,
VTE_STATUS AS ESTATUS,VTE_DOCTO AS FACTURA,COSTO,pen_isan AS ISAN,SUBTOTAL AS PRECIO,TOTAL,CLIENTE , CIUDAD ,
CANT=CASE WHEN SUBTOTAL >=0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END 
from libroventas where convert(datetime, vte_fechope,103) between 
convert(datetime,'01/01/2018',103) and convert(datetime,'01/04/2018',103) 
VENTA NOT LIKE 'INTERCAMBIO%' AND LIB_CVEUSU='GMI' ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear parámetros con los valores que necesites como filtro e invocar esos parámetros en la query SQL con `&nombre_parametro&`

Los parámetros los creas desde "Administrar parámetros" en el Editor de Power Query, especificando como valor texto la fecha de inicio y fin del filtro.

**Ejemplo:**

fechainicial: 01/01/2018

fechafinal: 01/04/2018

Query:

```
select CARLINE,veh_numserie AS SERIE,veh_anmodelo as MODELO,VENDEDOR,VENTA,VTE_FECHDOCTO AS FECHAFACTURA ,
VTE_STATUS AS ESTATUS,VTE_DOCTO AS FACTURA,COSTO,pen_isan AS ISAN,SUBTOTAL AS PRECIO,TOTAL,CLIENTE , CIUDAD ,
CANT=CASE WHEN SUBTOTAL >=0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END 
from libroventas where convert(datetime, vte_fechope,103) between 
"&fechainicial&" and "&fechainicial&" 
VENTA NOT LIKE 'INTERCAMBIO%' AND LIB_CVEUSU='GMI' ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Algo similar a Reporting Services, no lo encuentras en Power BI Desktop. Ahora bien, en el reporte que se genere, puedes definir un par de filtros o Slicers en donde el usuario indique, ya consultando el reporte, que filtre por los dos campos que indicas y obtenga sus datos.

Entiendo, aunque no lo he usado, que hay una manera de indicarle en el componente Power Query asociado a Power BI Desktop, para generar una nueva consulta, pero esto no es en tiempo de ejecución como requieres, sino en tiempo de diseño.

Algo sobre lo anterior en esta página Web: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/12/11/passing-parameters-to-sql-queries-with-value-nativequery-in-power-query-and-power-bi/